# git config core.fileMode false Not working on redhat git 1.7.1

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, redhat

I ran the following

```
chmod -R 777 directory
```

And all the permissions changed

When i run

```
git status
```

I got that all the file have been modified.

So I ran

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

But it does not seem to be working on my redhat and i still get all the files where modified after running `git status`

How can i ignore the mode change ?

I tried it on an ubuntu machine and it works

I am running git version 1.7.0.4 on my ubuntu machine
And git version 1.7.1 on my red hat

Any possible solution

Comment: What does "And got all over the place" mean? What doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get details, but you would have  **$HOME/.gitconfig**, .git/config** or .gitignore** and setting 'core.filemode=true' there.

1. Check
   `$ git config --global -l`
2. Check
   `$ git config -l|grep core.filemode`

   This may output more than one line... the last line seems to procede the others.

For more details, `$ man git`

Comment: I don't know why and it hears strange, but "-w" option for diff may work. There seems to exist many bugs for version 1.7 anyway...